# Cannot access variables in angular from d3 Funnel js callback

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

As per the latest document in D3 JS funnel I have click event callback as referred by the documentation. But when I'm unable to access functions from inside angular component using this.try().

Here is the implementation, don't know how to implement it.

**JS Code**

```
const options = {
          chart: { bottomPinch: 1, animate: 200, height: 300 },
          block: {
            // dynamicHeight: true,
            // dynamicSlope: true,
            highlight: true,
          },
          events: {
            click: {
              block(d) {
                console.log(d.label.raw);
                this.try(d.label.raw);
              },
            },
          },
          tooltip: { enabled: true, }
        };
        const chart = new D3Funnel('#d3Funnel');
        chart.draw(data, options);
      })
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="d3Funnel"></div>
```

It gives the error

```
ERROR TypeError: this.try is not a function
    at SVGPathElement.block
```

I don't know how to resolve this.

Reference of library
https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`block(d) { ... }` is just a shorthand for `block: function(d) { ... },` which would not lexically bind this.

If you replaced your event with an arrow function, such as `block: (d) => { ... }`, your code would be able to resolve this as you intend.